# How to fetch/scrape all elements from a html "class" which is inside "span"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-science

I am trying to **scrape** data from a website where i am collecting data from all elements under "class" which is inside "span" using this piece of code. But i am ending up in fetching only one element instead of all.

```
expand_hits = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "sold-property-listing"})
apartments = []
for hit_property in expand_hits:
    #element = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "sold-property-listing__location"})
    place_name = expand_hits[1].find("div", {"class": "sold-property-listing__location"}).findAll("span", {"class": "item-link"})[1].getText()
    print(place_name)
    apartments.append(final_str)
```

Expected result for print(place_name)

```
Stockholm
Malmö
Copenhagen
...
..
.
```

The result which is am getting for print(place_name)

```
Malmö
Malmö
Malmö
...
..
.
```

When i try to fetch the contents from expand_hits[1] i get only one element. If i don't specify the index  scraper is throwing an error regarding the usage find(), find_all() and findAll(). As far as i understood i think i have to call the content of the elements iteratively.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What's the url please and how many results are you expecting?

Comment: https://www.hemnet.se/salda/bostader?location_ids%5B%5D=474035 
I dont have the expecting results in number. Perhaps in thousands (guess)

Comment: I think you mean ‘scrape’. To scrap means to throw away.

Comment: Oops! My bad. That was a typo error. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the loop variable rather than indexing to same collection with same index (expand_hits[1]) and append place_name not final_str

```
expand_hits = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "sold-property-listing"})
apartments = []
for hit_property in expand_hits:
    place_name = hit_property.find("div", {"class": "sold-property-listing__location"}).find("span", {"class": "item-link"}).getText()
    print(place_name)
    apartments.append(place_name)
```

You only then need Find and no indexing

---

Add User-Agent header to ensure results. Also, I note that I have to pick a parent node because at least one result will not be captured by using that class item-link e.g. `Övägen 6C`. I use replace to get rid of the hidden text present due to now selecting for parent node.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.hemnet.se/salda/bostader?location_ids%5B%5D=474035"
page = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

for result in soup.select('.sold-results__normal-hit'):
    print(re.sub(r'\s{2,}',' ', result.select_one('.sold-property-listing__location h2 + div').text).replace(result.select_one('.hide-element').text.strip(), ''))
```

---

If you only want where in Malmo e.g.  `Limhamns Sjöstad`, you need to check how many child span tags there are for each listing.

```
for result in soup.select('.sold-results__normal-hit'):
    nodes = result.select('.sold-property-listing__location h2 + div span')
    if len(nodes)==2:
        place = nodes[1].text.strip()
    else:
        place = 'not specified'    
    print(place)
```

Comment: place_name = hit_property.find("div", {"class": "sold-property-listing__location"}).findAll("span", {"class": "item-link"})[1]
IndexError: list index out of range 
I am stuck with this error if i use the loop variable

Comment: Use Find as you are now at single result level. Also, you need an user-agent header in order to get any results

Comment: Got that. I see this returning text from another class instead of text from "item-link"
I want to return text from  this <span class="item-link">
          Limhamns Sjöstad,
</span>

Comment: Updated. Took a while because I saw there was a listing being missed and wanted to find a way to include it.

Comment: I think you want the last part of my answer

Comment: Amazing. It is not about the answer everytime it is about using the right technique. I appreciate your time and effort to answer my question. Cheers! :D
Don't remove any of your answers anymore. It might be useful for someone else :P